# Windows Apache2.2 PHP5 PHPMailer Error

Tags: php, windows, apache, phpmailer

I have been reading some older questions and I haven't found yet the solution to my problem.
Here it goes.

I'm developing a cool website with some mail functions, limited for admin users.
Right now I'm developing the site on localhost, but I've been provided with a Gmail account that will be used for the website.

I've been seeking through the web and the PHPMailer module seems a good election.

My idea is to send emails from my localhost to any other email address using the Gmail account.

Here are the codes I'm using.
For the Apache2.2 server

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

For php.ini

```
[mail function]
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_from = admins.domaing@gmail.com
```

And the php codes

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");   
  require_once("class.phpmailer.php"); 
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $body             = 'It works!';
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->Port       = 465; 
  $mail->Username   = "admins.domaing@gmail.com";
  $mail->Password   = "*********";
  $mail->SetFrom('admins.domaing@gmail.com', 'Admin');
  $mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic"; 
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);
  $address = "user@email.com";
  $mail->AddAddress($address, "user name");
  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
    echo "Message sent!";
  }
?>
```

Actually the error I'm getting is:

```
Invalid XML: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Obviously, the Gmail account is fake xD

Comment: If you solved your problem, post an answer below, and mark this answer as accepted (click the checkmark).

Answer (score 0):

Solution from the original poster:

Just change

`$mail->Username   = "admins.domaing@gmail.com";`

to

`$mail->Username   = "admins.domaing";`