# Send email using Fat Free Framework and SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to send an email using Fat Free Framework on localhost, using Gmail's SMTP server, but it does not send the mail. I'm also trying to use the F3 SMTP logging facility, but it returns nothing.

The output from the echo is: "email result: not sent, mylog: , header: does not exist".

I'm using the latest version of F3, with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4 on localhost.

```
$smtp = new SMTP ( 'smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'SSL', 'joebloggs@gmail.com', 'mypass' );

$smtp->set('From', '"Joe Bloggs" <joebloggs@gmail.com>');
$smtp->set('To', '<recipientname@gmail.com>');
$smtp->set('Subject', 'Sent with the F3 SMTP plug-in');  
$smtp->set('Errors-to', '<joebloggs@gmail.com>');  

$message = 'it works'; 

$sent = $smtp->send($message, TRUE);

$mylog = $smtp->log();

$sentText = 'not sent';

$headerText = 'does not exist';

if ($sent)
{
    $sentText = 'was sent';
}

if ($smtp->exists('Date'))
{
    $headerText = 'exists';
}

echo "email result: " . $sentText . ",mylog: " . $mylog . ", header: " . $headerText;
```

Comment: Have you tried another SMTP server? I'm pretty sure it won't work with F3, since Gmail requires STARTTLS which is not supported by F3.

Comment: just tested myself now. It works with SSL on 465 and TLS on port 587, but i had to activate the "Allowing less secure apps" option described on https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255.

Comment: though i really don't know why Google is blocking SSL/TLS, or what's missing here in the SMTP class. But STARTTLS is supported in here

Comment: maybe this resource helps: http://www.rocketideas.com/2012/05/gmail-error-password-not-accepted-from-server-solved/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the helpful comments.

I tried PHPMailer as Jacky suggested and (amazingly) I then got an error message from PHP to tell me exactly what the problem is.

The error message was "SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? "

So I went to my "php.ini" and searched for SSL and found the line "extension=php_openssl.dll" which was commented out. I uncommented it, re-started Apache and PHPMailer then worked - the email was sent.

I went back to Fat Free and that now worked too!  (no changes to the code posted in the question). It's a pity the Fat Free logging didn't give me any hints.

I used this code for PHPMailer:  [Example code for using PHPMailer on localhost (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521940/windows-apache2-2-php5-phpmailer-error)

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need PHPMailer for more test...
In the code of smtp.php from FLAT FREE, gmail seem to be work :( but with PHPMail it's official (in sample code they do it, and I use it and it's work).